# How add built-in textarea in theme development?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

How can I add built-in textarea in Wordpress v4 like when I hit Post -> Add new in theme development? I mean textarea with bbcode.

I need to add it to theme options page https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've used this plugin a ton for things like that.

This will work: https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/

Enjoy!